# How to listen to Actionbarsherlok menu item click from a fragment?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a main activity I am using actionbarsherlok, in which there is a menu item,

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Used to put dark icons on light action bar


        menu.add("Refresh")
        .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                          return false;
            }
        }).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

              return true;
    }
```

I have a fragment attached to this activity. What I want is to listen to the menu item click from main activity. I want to do some stuff in the fragment, when actionbar menu item is clicked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

First, id suggest to make your menus in menu.xml file then inflate it onCreateOptionsMenu. 
But anyways, in your sherlockFragmentActivity, give your menu item an id in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
menu.add(0, REFRESH_ID, 0, "Refresh").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Then override onOptionsItemSelected and return false (means to pass it to the fragment)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case REFRESH_ID:
            return false;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

then in your sherlockfragment class call onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected but return true this time to tell the system that the menu item has been handled.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case REFRESH_ID:
            refresh();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your fragment class should extends `SherlockFragment` class instead of `Fragment`, then you can override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`;